# Windows 11 64bit- Unable to install wxPython- ERROR: Could not build wheels for wxPython, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: wxpython, robotframework

I am receiving the below error, my python version is
C:\RobotFramework>py
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr 4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type “help”, “copyright”, “credits” or “license” for more information.

Note that i have already installed : attrdict. attrdict3. requests, MAVProxy and Cmake but i still receive the below error, please help to resolve.

I also tried to install
C:\RobotFramework>pip install wxPython
Collecting wxPython
Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) … done
Collecting pillow (from wxPython)
Using cached Pillow-9.5.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\robotframework\lib\site-packages (from wxPython) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\robotframework\lib\site-packages (from wxPython) (1.24.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: wxPython
Building wheel for wxPython (setup.py) … error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [47 lines of output]
C:\RobotFramework\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated ‘license-file’ will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name ‘license_file’ instead
warnings.warn(
C:\RobotFramework\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
C:\RobotFramework\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:317: DistDeprecationWarning: use_2to3 is ignored.
warnings.warn(f"{attr} is ignored.", DistDeprecationWarning)
running bdist_wheel
running build
Will build using: “C:\RobotFramework\python.exe”
3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr 4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python’s architecture is 64bit
cfg.VERSION: 4.2.0

Running command: build
Running command: build_wx
Command '"C:\RobotFramework\python.exe" -c "import os, sys, setuptools.msvc; setuptools.msvc.isfile = lambda path: path is not None and os.path.isfile(path); ei = setuptools.msvc.EnvironmentInfo('x64', vc_min_ver=14.0); env = ei.return_env(); env['vc_ver'] = ei.vc_ver; env['vs_ver'] = ei.vs_ver; env['arch'] = ei.pi.arch; env['py_ver'] = sys.version_info[:2]; print(env)"' failed with exit code 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "C:\RobotFramework\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1120, in **init**

self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)

```
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

File "C:\RobotFramework\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 596, in **init**

vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vs_ver())

```
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

File "C:\RobotFramework\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 610, in _find_latest_available_vs_ver

raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: No Microsoft Visual C++ version found
Finished command: build_wx (0.313s)
Finished command: build (0.313s)
WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been
generated already. If that is not the case then use build.py directly
to generate the source and perform the build stage. You can use
--skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this
message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.

"C:\RobotFramework\python.exe" -u build.py build
Command '"C:\RobotFramework\python.exe" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxPython
Running setup.py clean for wxPython
Failed to build wxPython
ERROR: Could not build wheels for wxPython, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no installable packages (wheel) for wxPython 4.2.0, on Python 3.11 for Windows. That is why the system is trying to build, which is a complex operation. There is some discussion about this in https://discuss.wxpython.org and someone mentioned a build at https://alldunn.visualstudio.com/wxPython-CI/_build?definitionId=2 . You should try to install from an existing build, if you find one.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the new release of wxPython 4.2.1. [Here is the announcement](https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/wxpython-4-2-1-released/36534?u=helio_guilherme).

Comment: This is amazing news, thank you so much!! its installed successfully... much appreciated!